# Azure Pipelines - Re-using restored nuget packages between stages

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm currently restoring my packages with the DotNetCoreCli@2 restore task in my first stage. Then, in my second stage, I'd like to run my unit tests. However, when I run my tests with the DotNetCoreCli@2 test task in the second stage, the task starts of by restoring the projects. Meaning that the second stage doesn't find the restored projects from the first stage. If I restore the projects and run the unit tests in the same stage, no extra restore is run. Is it possible to reference the restored projects from stage one in stage two?

The stages contain more stuff in practice, so it would be preferable not to have to merge them.

Here is an example of the setup, with the comments pointing to where I'd expect some additional tasks to be needed:

```yaml
stages:
 - stage: one
   jobs:
   - job: restoreJob 
     steps:
     - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
       displayName: Restore Projects
       inputs: 
         command: restore
         projects: '**/*.csproj'
     # A sequence of tasks to allow referencing of the restore in Stage 'two' here..

 - stage: two
   jobs:
   - job: unitTestJob 
     steps:
     # A sequence of tasks to reference the restored projects from Stage 'one' here..
     - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
       displayName: Unit Test Projects
       inputs: 
         command: test
         projects: '**/*.UnitTests.csproj'
         arguments: '--configuration release --collect "Code coverage"'
```

Comment: You can share output between stages with the `publish` and `download` task aliases. You can also use the `cache` task alias which works in conjunction with your package manager to handle caching packages between pipeline runs. Refer to the documentation for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I figured it might be a combo of publish and download, but I've not been able to find anything on how to do it for restored projects. I'll dig deeper into it. Might modify/edit my question towards those tasks later.

Comment: [`cache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops) might be more what you're looking for in this case.

Comment: @IsakEngström can you post the code that fixed the issue?